# How to prevent a simple table to become one enhanced Laravel grid table

Tags: laravel

How do I prevent the enhancement of the tables within Laravel ?

I have multiple tables on the current page.

The first table is a fully functional laravel grid table, having filters, the search box, order capable, etc ..

The other tables should be simple tables, but, somehow, they all inherit all the features described above.

The source code of my simple table looks like:

```
<table id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id{{$value['id']}}"
                               class="table-bordered table-striped">

                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Farmacia</th>
                                <th>Au dat</th>
                                <th>Nu au dat</th>
                                <th>Procent promovare</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

This is what laravel does to my simple tables:

```
<div id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper container-fluid dt-bootstrap4 no-footer"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><div class="dataTables_length" id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_length"><label>Show <select name="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_length" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" class="form-control form-control-sm"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><div id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" type="search"></label></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><table id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" class="table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_info"><thead>
                            <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 55px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Farmacia: activate to sort column descending">Farmacia</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 39.8167px;" aria-label="Au dat: activate to sort column ascending">Au dat</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 58.7px;" aria-label="Nu au dat: activate to sort column ascending">Nu au dat</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 115.15px;" aria-label="Procent promovare: activate to sort column ascending">Procent promovare</th></tr>
                            </thead>



                            <tbody>

                            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                            </tr></tbody>

                        </table><div id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_processing" class="dataTables_processing card" style="display: none;">Processing...</div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5"><div class="dataTables_info" id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries</div></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_paginate"><ul class="pagination"><li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Previous</a></li><li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="#" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" class="page-link">1</a></li><li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="table_container_user_role_coordonator_id5" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Next</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the jQuery plug-in Datatables installed in your code base. I would suggest looking at the javascript code and finding the jQuery selector used.

If you only want one table to be enhanced by Datatables then you can write a selector by id, such as:

```
$(“#table_id_1”).Datatable();
```

Please post the related javascript code if you can.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer; I don't have any jQuery code, it's only the standard Laravel code;